# How to render fbx models in react js using three.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, fbx

so i was trying to render fbx models in three.js using react. I used this [three-npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three) and [three-fbx-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-fbx-loader) to load the fbx model. I used the [samba dancing fbx](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/fbx/Samba%20Dancing.fbx) from three.js examples and tried to render it to the screen like this.

```
componentDidMount(){
     const width = this.mount.clientWidth
     const height = this.mount.clientHeight

     const scene = new THREE.Scene()
     const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
       75,
       width / height,
       0.1,
       1000
     ) 

     const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true })
     camera.position.z = -35;
     var fbxLoader = new FBXLoader();
     fbxLoader.load('Samba Dancing.fbx', obj => {
        console.log('MODEL: ', obj);
        scene.add(obj);
     });
}
```

here is the attached screenshot [image]

The model is not being displayed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `renderer.render()` anywhere?

Comment: Yes i have, i just shared the piece of code related to the fbx. If i render any geometry it gets rendered perfectly.